# R Challenge With Shaping From Long to Wide

Tags: r, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("StudentID"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
        "Class"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
        "Grade"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
        "Time"=c(11,12,13,15,17,17,18,6,7,8,9),
        "Fail"=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        "Score"=c(6,6,5,6,9,10,7,9,7,9,6))



data2=data.frame("StudentID"=c(1,2,3),
        "Class"=c(1,1,2),
        "Fail"=c(1,0,0),
        "Time1"=c(11,15,6),
        "Score1"=c(6,6,9),
        "Time2"=c(12,17,7),
        "Score2"=c(6,9,7),
        "Time3"=c(13,17,8),
        "Score3"=c(5,10,9),
        "Time4"=c(-99,18,9),
        "Score4"=c(-99,7,6))
```

I have 'data1' and wish for 'data2' by reshaping 'data1' as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you can use `dcast` from `data.table` package (special thanks to @RonakShah to pointed out the use of `fill = -99` as argument to fill missing values):

```r
dcast(setDT(data1), StudentID+Class+Fail ~ Grade, value.var = c("Time","Score"), fill = -99)

   StudentID Class Fail Time_1 Time_2 Time_3 Time_4 Score_1 Score_2 Score_3 Score_4
1:         1     1    1     11     12     13    -99       6       6       5     -99
2:         2     1    0     15     17     17     18       6       9      10       7
3:         3     2    0      6      7      8      9       9       7       9       6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` methods

```
out <- reshape(data1, idvar = c('StudentID', 'Class', 'Fail'),
           timevar = 'Grade', direction = 'wide')
replace(out, is.na(out), -99)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(
  data1,
  names_from = Grade,
  values_from = c(Time, Score),
  values_fill = list(Score = -99, Time = -99)
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#  StudentID Class  Fail Time_1 Time_2 Time_3 Time_4 Score_1 Score_2 Score_3 Score_4
#      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1         1     1     1     11     12     13    -99       6       6       5     -99
#2         2     1     0     15     17     17     18       6       9      10       7
#3         3     2     0      6      7      8      9       9       7       9       6
```